# What is the "parameter on the squares of the ordinates" w.r.t. a parabola?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, conic-sections, math-history, geometric-construction

I'm going through some constructions and derivations in the English Translation of [On Burning Mirrors - Diocles, Pg 44](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/hist_206r_2009/Too_1976.pdf) but I'm unable to understand a particular statement w.r.t. to the construction below:

[image: Inverted Parabola]

Here is the explanation of the construction:

[image: Explanation of Construction]
[image]

What exactly is $BH$ and how does one draw it? The statement *"...let half the parameter of the squares on the ordinates be line $BH$"* is a bit confusing. What's the modern equivalent translation?

(Background context: [Discovery of the focus/directrix property](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7101/how-was-the-focus-directrix-property-of-conic-sections-discovered))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter of the ordinates, also called "latus rectum", is that length $BH$ such that, for any point $\Theta$ of the parabola, $\Theta G^2=BH\cdot BG$.

In modern terms, if $y=ax^2$ is the equation of the parabola, then $BH=1/a$. Traditionally, the latus rectum was drawn starting from the vertex of the parabola, perpendicular to its axis. See Prop. I 11 in Apollonius (Proposition 1 in Heath's translation).

EDIT.

Notice, however, that the Diocles' defines $BH$ as "half the parameter of the ordinates", hence the semi-latus rectum. We have then $\Theta G^2=2BH\cdot BG$. This approach was common before Apollonius' treatise.

Comment: So, was the modern "latus rectum" *shifted* to coincide with the focus?

Comment: Yes: I suppose the modern definition is probably easier to retain, but the meaning of the "latus rectum" can be understood only if you think that equation $\Theta G^2=BH\cdot BG$ was written by Apollonius as "the square of side $\Theta G$ is equal to rectangle $HBG$.

Comment: See however my edit.